# How do I show a blank screen with a message on my app launch instead of splashscreen on tablets?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-launcher, android-compatibility, android-tablet-layout

I am planning to restrict my app to tablets but in the sense that I don't want to add compatibility screen etc. options in `manifest`. Currently, on app launch my `manifest` has a `splashscreenactivity` which launches for about 3 seconds then moves on to another fragment.
I already have the code in my app that detects if the device is a tablet or not (`say istablet()`) , I was wondering if there is a way I can display black screen with a `TextView` on app launch for tablets letting the user know the app is not compatible on tablets rather than splash screen and follow up fragment.

Any ideas?

Can I call the layout in the application class somehow for the black screen and restrict it from routing further for tablets?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Did you try to use width qualifiers? https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes

Comment: Well you can use a tablet layout defined in tablet res folder with same name as your splash layout, activity remains same and just check if its tablet do not move to next view.

Comment: isnt there a better way to do this even before the launch activity kicks in, for instance in application class?

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi I already have width qualifiers in values, just want to see if I can use them in my application class even before launch activity gets called. is there an easy weay to do this